# Dynamically add filter in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-filter

I am building a table where the rows and columns are built entirely based on the data that is sent to it.

I'm very close to having it work, I'm having trouble figuring out how to build a custom filter and pass in the filter patterns dynamically

**The object that makes up the columns** looks like

```
{ name: 'transactionDate', displayName: 'Date / Time', displayOrder: 1, filter: "date: 'MM/dd/yy hh:mm a'" }
```

**The object that makes up the transaction** for the rows looks like this:

```
{ transactionDate: '2015-06-11', transactionType: 'This Type', transactionAmount: 25 }
```

**The HTML** I have is this:

```
<td ng-repeat="col in columns">{{transaction[col.name] | dynamicFilter: col.filter}}</td>
```

**The filter** I currently have built is:

```
function dynamicFilter($filter) {
    return function (value, filter) {
        console.log(filter);
        console.log(value);
        var test = $filter(filter)(value);
        return test;
    }
}
```

Both filter and value are getting passed correctly. I'm having trouble figuring out how to apply the filter to the value before returning. A value that might be passed in would `2015-06-10T16:17:14` be and a filter that would be passed in could be `date: 'MM/dd/yy hh:mm a'` to create date/time filter. Or `21` and `currency` for a dollar value.

***I would like to be able to use Angular's built in features in a similar way you could on the view***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For these dynamic filters that have partial params (such as the format you're providing with date), you have to remove the param from the filter and apply it later.

So `filter: "date: 'MM/dd/yy hh:mm a'"`, needs to be just `filter: "date"`.

The additional constraint, `MM/dd/yy hh:mm a`, would be sent along with the value `$filter(filter)(value, 'MM/dd/yy hh:mm a');`

To do this generically, you can take advantage of `apply`. The Object can be:

`{filter: { type: "date", params: ['MM/dd/yy hh:mm a'] } }`

And the directive can have (assuming you send the params as well):

```
var filterFn = $filter(filter.type); 
return filterFn.apply(filterFn, [value].concat(filter.params));
```

**EDIT**: here's a JSFiddle with two buttons, the first demonstrates your original approach with "date: 'MM/dd/yy hh:mm a'", and the second demonstrates applied approach that I outline above http://jsfiddle.net/4whemakt/

Comment: I'm working down this path and when I step through filterFn gets assigned to `filterFn = (date, format, timezone)` as expected. However, the return isn't coming back with anything

Comment: Should be `$filter('date')(value, format, timezone);`. Which is can be similarly called as `var filterFn = $filter('date'); filterFn.apply(filterFn, [value, format, timezone]);` . The JSFiddle demo that I added to the answer should help.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply and return the filtered value conditionally in your dynamicFilter. Something like this

```
function dynamicFilter($filter) {
    return function (value, filter) {
        if (filter.indexOf('date:') !== -1) {
           //Note: I am using moment js to format the date
           return moment(value).format(filter.match(/'([^']+)'/)[1]);
        }
        else {
            return $filter(filter)(value)
        }
    }
}
```

moment.js reference http://momentjs.com/

Comment: But can I use the built in filters that angularjs uses?

Comment: You can use if that meets your requirement. `filter.match(/'([^']+)'/)[1]` in my answer will extract and give you the date format string from the filter.

Comment: But them I'm writing custom rules for things that Angular already has built in. I need one for currency too. Seem like some duplication

Comment: It actually depends on what you need. If what angular provides helps you then it is always better to use it instead of writing your own filters.